# Rename the column name of a stored function

Tags: postgresql, return

I've got a postgresql stored procedure, which is returning an integer.
When I call that function, the result is returned with the function name as column name.

For example the name of the function is: "add-person". The column name, when invoking the function, is "add-person".

Is there a way to make the database return the integer with a self-choosen column name? For example "id"?

I think it is pretty easy, but I currently miss the forests for the trees..

Edit:
What i'd missed to tell, is that the return value is a variable, like so:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "scheme"."add-person"(arggivenname character varying, argfamilyname character varying) RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
  varResponse integer;

BEGIN
-- Operations before

INSERT INTO "scheme"."table"
(
  given_name,
  family_name
)
VALUES
(
  arggivenname,
  argfamilyname
)
RETURNING
  "id"
INTO
  varResponse;

-- Operations after

RETURN varResponse;

END;

$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

Comment: Can you show us the *complete* function?

Comment: Hello a_horse_with_no_name, I can not copy all the code. But I hope the  code above helps. I already thought something like RETURN varResponse AS "id" would help, but in fact, it did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can us the AS statement for that. That means:

```
     Select add-person() AS yourcolumnname
```

Comment: Hello Bine, thank you for your response! But I would like to make the change at the database side :/

Comment: Why do you want to change it on database side? You told that you get just an integer value back. What do you want to do with the renamed column name?

Comment: That is true. There is a php script, which expects to get the value via pg_fetch_assoc (associative array). It is searching for the column name "id". Changing the php script isn't possible. That is the reason, why I'm asking :/

Comment: How do you call your add-person function and pg_fetch_assoc? Is it something like $result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT add-person()"); , pg_fetch_assoc($result)? In this case you can use my solution with the alias, because $result is a "table" with columnname id and your integer value; an example for that is here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: The request: `$response = pg_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM \"scheme\".\"add-person\"($givenName, $familyName)");`. The interpretation: `$row = pg_fetch_assoc($response); return $row['id'];` I am sorry, if this causes annoyance

Comment: You can use a alias there. Try:
$response = pg_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM \"scheme\".\"add-person\"($givenName, $familyName) AS id;"
The interpretation is the one you have

Comment: @Steffen you **need** to rewrite the logic in your php file, it's open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). -- if you're willing to do that, an alias in the query is the most simple solution, like in Bine's answer (but if the function name contains special characters like `-`, it should be quoted).

Comment: I would, if there would be a way to change the script. For this project, I only have full access to the DBMS, but no access to change the script. Reading is possible. Well, I will persuade him. Thanks to all involved.

Answer (score 2):

To have a named column from a function it is necessary to create a `type` and return that `type` from the function

```
create type mytype as (mycolumn integer);

create or replace function ri()
returns mytype as $$
select 1;
$$ language sql;

select * from ri();
 mycolumn 
----------
        1
```

### Edit

Or much simpler without the `type` creation as in @pozs comment:

```
create or replace function ri(out mycolumn integer)
as $$
select 1;
$$ language sql;
```

Comment: Nice trick, but `select ri()` will give a "strange" (=unexpected) result in this case.

Comment: @a_horse The real solution is to give the column an alias as in Bine's answer which he refused because he did not pay attention to it.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto a single `out mycolumn integer` parameter (& without the `returns` clause) the function can work both ways. However, if called as `select ri()` will still return the column as `ri`.